# How to remove strict mysql_mode for just 1 database, not global?

Tags: mysql, percona

I have done some research on removing the strict mysql mode, and it appears everything is for a global update on all my databases.

Is there any way to remove it for just 1 database? And keep it a permanent solution that won't be reset if mysql resets?

Comment: SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';

Comment: Thanks @Bart, but where do I do that? Is that server side or code side?  I'm running a full piece of software already developed using ZF2 and looking to make this an easy change.  Is there a way to set that session per user, or somewhere on the server that won't get updated?

Comment: @Kyle You do that in the client code. It just modifies the mode for the current connection.

Comment: The answer to the question is "no".